# Path style in excess-router doesn't work properly

Tags: routes, polymer, iron-router

I'm working with excess-router element for Polymer 1.0 and it works fine despite one small thing. By default this polymer element is using "hash" sign in the url but I'd like change it to usual path style such as "/" (**path-style="path"**). So I'm doing it like this:

```
            <excess-router-config manual-start path-style="path"></excess-router-config>
            <excess-route route="/(.*)?" redirect-to="/profile" activation-modifiers="x"></excess-route>
            <excess-route route="/:mainmenu/(.*)?" mainmenu="{{appRoute}}"></excess-route>
```

it works but when I'm switching language on my website then I'm getting error message: **"The requested URL /example_url was not found on this server."**

I don't know where should I handle it and why it does work by "hash" style "#/example_url"

Answer (score 0):

Path style uses the browser's History API. In order to use it properly, you'll have to rewrite your server rules to properly redirect on those paths.

Here's an example: http://readystate4.com/2012/05/17/nginx-and-apache-rewrite-to-support-html5-pushstate/